# Conditional Replace Values

Tags: r

I have a data set called NFL. I am trying to flag PlayType by "Sack", replace the NA in PlayerPosition with "QB", and then go back to normal. I can't figure out the code to make it happen. So far I have this which is wrong:

```
 NFL$PlayerPosition[NFL$PlayType == "Sack"] <- "QB"
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example that indicates what is wrong and what the expected results look like.

Answer (score 1):

This works?

```
NFL[NFL$PlayType == "Sack",]$PlayerPosition <- "QB"
```

Is this what you are trying to do? It should work.

```
#Create dummy data
NFL <- data.frame(PlayType = c("A","B","C","Sack"),PlayerPosition = c(NA,NA,NA,NA))

#filter
NFL[NFL$PlayType == "Sack",]$PlayerPosition <- 'QA'
```

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work. By "going back to normal," I mean I am continuing my work on the NFL data set after the change is applied.

Comment: @Kaela I missed the , to filter rows. Try it again

Comment: I fixed it but no success.

Comment: Are you creating a new playerposition column? or are you editing an existing one.

Comment: It is an existing one.

Comment: do you get an error when you run it? Which error? Or it doesn't change what you want it to change?